# Scheduled job (send_reminder) failing since upgrading to 5.64.2

Tags: scheduled-reminders

I upgraded to 5.64.2 on WordPress 6.3.1 yesterday and since then I'm seeing scheduled job failures. There's no error showing in the logs in ConfigAndLog but this is appearing next to each scheduled job:

```
Entity: Job Action: send_reminder
Summary
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: no such field
Details

Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Failure, Error message: DB Error: no such field
```

If I run the job manually it works fine, but when it's triggered from cron it seems to be failing. Is there anything I can do to debug what's happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a permissions problem when run as cron? How are you running cron?

Comment: I had a similar problem after upgrading to 5.63.3, but on Drupal. Cron stopped working, and the fix (I think, not 100% sure) was to unblock the cron user.  In Drupal you can block a user, and up to now this has been a good way to have a user that works in cron but cannot login.  Maybe there was a change in Civi so blocked users cannot  be used in this situation? Anyway, I unblocked the user & cron worked again.

Comment: See my earlier comment - I tested again on a 5.64.1 system & confirm that a user for cron who is blocked will stop cron working.  This is on a Drupal 7 & there's a message in the Drupal log 'Exception: Sorry, can not load CMS user account. in CRM_Utils_System_Drupal->loadBootStrap() (line 549 of /home/acivior1/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/System/Drupal.php).'  A change must have been made sometime after 5.58.  If this fixes your problem please let me know and I'll make it the answer.

Comment: What's strange is that other cron jobs are running fine (including scheduled mailings) - it's just this one that doesn't run

Comment: I've tried running the cron job as a super admin user and it fires fine. I suspect there's a deprecated merge tag in a reminder somewhere as it doesn't always fail. Is there a way to dig into which reminders were attempted to be sent?